# SSH client for Android with scp and sftp features

Tags: ssh

I have tried SSHjuice and Termius and neither of these have the scp features ( I couldn't find it in the free/trial version ).
So can anybody tell me is there any SSH client (free version) for Android that have scp (secure copy ) or sftp features.
I couldn't find it in Google. thanks .

Comment: Install openssh on Termux

Comment: Related: [How to run SSH/SFTP server for multiple user logins with password authentication](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209919/218526).

Answer (score 5):

For ssh and scp, use Termux. It's a full-feature Linux-type terminal for Android. Use it like a normal Linux terminal.

Sftp, scp, and ssh are all included in the OpenSSH package.

It's also free and open-source

1. Download [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux).
2. `apt update && apt upgrade`
3. To install OpenSSH run `pkg install openssh`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Is it possible to install the SSH server as well in termux ?

Comment: @JustKhaithang I do not think so, not without root it won't work

Comment: I just installed tmux and SSH client and I want to copy a file to my android from my Linux server. what would be the command for that ?

Comment: Standard Linux usage. See scp --help

Comment: in tmux my home directory is 
`/data/data/com.termux/files/home` . So do I have specify this path for the target destination? that's what I wanted to know.

Comment: @JustKhaithang if termux has storage permission just push to /sdcard