# How to SCP files from a PC to storage in Termux

Tags: external-sd, file-transfer, ssh, termux

I can scp files from my Linux server to Termux directory on my Android smartphone but Termux directory is not accessible through file explorer. What exactly should be the destination path for scp so that it places the file in the storage, say in the `Download` directory which is accessible through the file explorer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH client for Android with scp and sftp features](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209572/ssh-client-for-android-with-scp-and-sftp-features)

Answer (score 2):

By design Android won't allow any other app to access Termux's data directory: `/data/data/com.termux/files/home`. However you can `scp` directly to SD card after granting `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

As referenced in [Termux wiki](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-setup-storage):

> It is necessary to grant storage permission for Termux on Android 6 and higher. Use 'Settings>Apps>Termux>Permissions>Storage' and set to true.

Now to copy files to Download directory:

```
~$ scp <file_name> <phone_IP>:/sdcard/Download/
```

**RELATED:** [How to run SSH/SFTP server for multiple user logins with password authentication on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209919/218526)